# Trying to figure out why a thrown error is not caught

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, try-catch, es6-promise

Here's the complete code I'm trying to run. I will, however, censor the url of the website for personal reasons. I am trying to **scrape** titles from a very slow website which occasionally sends error status codes in the 4xx range because that, so to handle that I throw an error then retry fetching the same pages after a couple of seconds. The problem is that this error is never caught by the "catch" block. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
const URL = "https://webpage.com/page=";
const SELECTOR = ".post-title.entry-title>a";
const MAX_CONCURRENT_FETCH = 5;
const NB_OF_PAGES = 125;
const ERROR_WAIT_TIME = 20000;

const titles = [];
const parser = new DOMParser();


function fetchPages() {

  helper(1, MAX_CONCURRENT_FETCH);

  function helper(first, last) {
    const requests = [];

    console.log("\n" + "*".repeat(40));
    for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) {
      requests.push(fetch(URL + i));
      console.log(`Fetching page: ${i}`);
    }
    console.log("*".repeat(40) + "\n");

    try {
      Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
        responses.forEach(async(response, i) => {

          /* if no code errors, parse the page, extract the titles then add them to the "titles" array */
          if (response.ok) {
            const htmlPage = await response.text();
            console.log("\n" + "*".repeat(40));
            console.log(`Extracting titles from page: ${first+i}`);
            console.log("*".repeat(40) + "\n");
            const htmlObject = parser.parseFromString(htmlPage, "text/html");
            htmlObject.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR).forEach(node => {
              titles.push(node.textContent);
              console.log(`Title: ${node.textContent}`);
            });
          }

          /* code error, get out of the forEach method by throwing an error */
          else {
            console.log("*".repeat(40) + "\n");
            console.log("Throwing error...");
            throw {
              response: response
            }
          }
        });

        /* keep fetching until the last page */
        if (last + 1 < NB_OF_PAGES)
          helper(last + 1, last + MAX_CONCURRENT_FETCH);

        /*  once all pages have been fetched, show the result on screen */
        else showResult();
      });
    }

    /* catch the error that was throw inside the forEach method, show the status code error and how long before the pages will be fetched again */
    catch (err) {
      console.log("Error captured...");
      console.log(`Status Code: ${err.response.status}, retrying in ${ERROR_WAIT_TIME/1000} seconds.`);
      console.log("*".repeat(40) + "\n");
      setTimeout(() => helper(first, last), ERROR_WAIT_TIME);
    }

  }
}

function showResult() {
  const uniqueTitles = [...new Set(titles)].sort();
  const titlesUl = document.createElement("ul");

  uniqueTitles.forEach(title => {
    const titleLi = document.createElement("li");
    titleLi.textContent = title;
    titlesUl.appendChild(titleLi);
  });

  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.body.appendChild(titlesUl);
}

fetchPages();
```

Answer (score 0):

The try...catch statement contains Promises.all(). This is a non-blocking asynchronous function. The try...catch only applies to initializing the Promises.all() function, it does not catch resolved Promises.

Also note that you are sending all fetch requests in parallel, this may overload the server somewhat. It would be more polite to fire requests one by one using async await.

Comment: Any suggestion on what I can do instead? I need to get out of the forEach whenever there's an html code error, the only way is by throwing an error. As for the parallel requests, I only send 5 at time and when all 5 are resolved 5 others will be fetched.

Comment: Yes, but your question was about why the try-catch was not working.

Comment: try somethin like: async function(){for all urls..{try...result = await fetch(url)}...catch..}

Comment: the fetch api doesn't throw an exception if it get code 404 or 4xx in general. That's why I have to check it with "response.ok" and manually throw an error.